# Import or Sync Outlook calendar meeting invites to Sharepoint calendar list

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I want my outlook calendar meeting invites to be visible in my Sharepoint calendar.

I do not want to create new calendar just import or sync all the meeting from my outlook calendar to Sharepoint calendar list.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps to connect Outlook with SharePoint Calendar.

**Connect SharePoint Calendar with Outlook**:

1. Open the SharePoint calendar you wish to connect.
2. Click the Calendar tab at the top left of the screen to open the ribbon.
3. Select the Connect to Outlook option from the Connect & Export group on the ribbon.
4. If prompted to allow the website to run a program on your computer, click Allow.
5. If prompted for the website to open web content, click Allow.
6. A Microsoft Office Outlook dialog box will appear, click Advanced to open a SharePoint List Options dialog box.
7. In the Folder Name text box, enter a name for the calendar.
8. Optionally, enter a Description for the calendar.
9. Click OK.
10. Click Yes to link the calendar to Outlook.

**Reference**:

[Connect SharePoint Calendar to your Outlook Calendar](https://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/connect-sharepoint-2013-calendar-to-your-outlook-calendar).

Comment: This option I have already tried. It creates another calendar in my outlook. I do not want any extra calendar, just map the events and invites in my outlook calendar to the sharepoint calendar.

Answer (score 1):

There is not away to sync an outlook calendar to SharePoint, you can only sync a SharePoint Calendar to Outlook.  Once synced outlook then can write to the SharePoint calendar, but the calendar has to originate in SharePoint.